# tableView(canEditRowAt) no longer working with tableViewDiffableDataSource

Tags: uitableview, delete-row, editing, uitableviewdiffabledatasource

I created a fairly simple tableView for selecting a category for an item model. Everything was working fine yesterday. Today I have been trying to switch the tableView data source over to a `UITableViewDiffableDataSource` as I want to wrap my head around the API.  I have the entire tableView back up and running EXCEPT I can no longer edit my rows!

the `setEditing` logic works as the `newCategoryButton` is disabled when I tap the edit button in the navigation bar and is enabled when I tap it again. However, I am never able to swipe to delete and the delete icons do not show up next to my rows in editing mode.

I tried removing `setEditing`, emptying out `commit editingStyle` and simply setting `canEditRow` to `return true` and still nothing.

Any help would be greatly appreciate. Thank!

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    let section = dataSource.snapshot().sectionIdentifiers[indexPath.section]
    if section == .noneSelected {
        return false
    } else {
    return true
    }
}

override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setEditing(editing, animated: true)
    if editing == true {
        newCategoryButton.isEnabled = false
    } else {
        newCategoryButton.isEnabled = true
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        categories.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    let movedCategory = categories.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
    categories.insert(movedCategory, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
}
```

[screenShot after edit button is tapped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p54Np.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trouble is that `canEditRowAt` is a *data source method*. You (the view controller) are now not the data source; the diffable data source is. You need to implement this method *inside the diffable data source*. That's typically done by subclassing the diffable data source class, so that you can override this method. Otherwise, the diffable data source just returns its default value — which is `false`, which is why you currently can't edit any rows.

Comment: Here's an example: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/604368f458076dd40a8f4d0676a2aa79adb8e390/bk2ch08p445deleteTableRowsDiffable/ch21p718sections/RootViewController.swift

Comment: Hey thank you. So this solved the problem of not being able to edit the tableView.  However it has created a new one of no longer updating my properties in the VC and I can't seem to mutate them from the override function in the datasource subclass, presumable because they haven't been assigned yet.

Comment: That would require a whole new question. :)